# Servers That Implement Ethereum RPC

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, testrpc, rpc

Here is the documentation for Ethereum RPC. It looks straight forward enough, but I just need a list of servers that implement the RPC.

https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/ethereum_json_rpc.html

Can I get some Urls to hit so I can actually this working?

*Note: I am not trying to run a node locally. I need to hit an existing stable API server which already exposes the RPC calls to the web.*

Answer (score 1):

A good way to test rpc calls is to run a node locally, either a real ethereum node like [Parity](https://www.parity.io/) or [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/) or a simulator like [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) (formerly known as testrpc).

Alternatively, you can interact with the live network or testnets via [Infura](https://infura.io/), which provides free live RPC endpoints

Comment: Parity and Geth look like actual nodes. I'm not trying to run a node. I'm just trying to hit a Ethereum API of an existing node. So, are you saying that Infura provides a live RPC endpoints?

Comment: What are the URLs for the endpoints?

Comment: You have to make an account, and it gives you an endpoint. It's free and just requires an email

Comment: That sounds very good. Are there other services that do this?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this one for Ethereum Classic:

https://web3.gastracker.io

http://help.gastracker.io/support/solutions/articles/36000000934-public-json-rpc-api